# Android LinearLayout get views/rows that are on the screen

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have a `LinearLayout` set to vertical and i've added 100 views to it each view is 50dp high.  A user is going to scroll and fling up and down on that `LinearLayout`.

I need to know the index numbers of the views that are on the screen. i.e if they fling down to the middle and stop, and see 5 items on their screen, i'd need to infer 50-55.

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@id/listing_main">
            </LinearLayout>
```

I've tried a bunch of ways to infer the current visible views - like taking the `scrollY` position and the height of my items...doesn't seem to work out.

`view.getScrollY()` seems totally arbitrary compared to the other scroll mesurements

Comment: Use a ListActivity, well, or what are you trying to do??

Comment: I don't think a list activity is an option for me here - it's a rather complicated screen that gets built through several async tasks with views being inflated and added to the layout. A solution where I can get the visible position of a linear layout would be ideal.  In other words, everything is working perfectly this way and i just need this one solution. I think i can rework it to use a listactivity but i'd rather not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put them inside a list then you can use `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()` and use these to get all of them from first to last.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html

Comment: I'll take that if you want to know what items in a list are on the screen then a list activity is the way to go. For my purposes, simply dividing the current view.getScrollY() by the height of the objects in the list gives me a close enough range to do what i need to do. Thanks.